# XmlHTTPRequest sample code does not work

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to write a simple Javascript program that will fetch a text file and display it using alert. So, being optimistic, I went to the w3schools page that purports to offer sample programs and I tried one:

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_first

It doesn't work. I substituted their URL for mine. I played with their code in an attempt to get it to work. Still nothing.

I have a sneaking suspicion that my file, which is hosted on Comcast, is not being read because Comcast is blocking Javascript access to files.
But I hope I am wrong. I also tried http://yahoo.com, and still I get a zero-byte response.

Here is my latest code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv" > xyz </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var xmlHttp = null;
function writeDiv (divName, content)
{
     document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = content;
}
function Fetch()
{
    var Url = "http://yahoo.com";
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "processing...";
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ProcessRequest;
    xmlHttp.open("GET", Url, true );
    xmlHttp.send(null );
}
function ProcessRequest()
{
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        writeDiv ("myDiv", xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
}
Fetch();
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Help?

Answer (score 5):

1. You can't access data on other sites. The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents this for security reasons.
2. You have commented out your JavaScript, so it won't execute (if the file is processed as XHTML instead of HTML). I wrote [an article on the subject](http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/) a while ago if you want more details.
3. Don't trust W3S. See http://w3fools.com/
4. `new XMLHttpRequest()` won't work on older versions of Internet Explorer (according to leeeb, support for that syntax was added in IE 7)

Comment: XMLHttpRequest was native from IE7.

Comment: From curiosity, just scanned through the w3s pages to see if there is any mention of the origin policy.  I can't see one, which is really poor considering this is such a frequently asked question.

Comment: @leeeb: Do you expect anything else from w3schools? ;)